# Extracting the year from text Date column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to extract the year from the order_date column but this is what happens.
The formula I used is `=IF(AND(L2 < 10, M2 = 9), MID(B2,14,4), MID(B2,13,4))*1`. 
I used the formula for the month of September which has a shortened form of Sept and for the days that is less than 10. 
How can I fix the formula? 
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: So give us some data that we can copy & paste and we might play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(B2,", ")+0,3)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=MAX(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2,{13,14},5),",",)+0)
```

---

Comment: This worked but can't convert it to a number.

Comment: @DexPapa the screenshot shows those are already converted to a number. Can you show me what you are facing issues with. Because once you extract it can easily be converted by either using a double unary or multiplying with one, however i have already done that using adding a `0`

Comment: It first show that cannot change a part of the array, I tried it again and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @DexPapa glad it worked out for you =)

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines (no need for `IF()` either):

```
=--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(B2:B22,",",2),",")
```

Or, since the year is the only substring of 5 characters between comma:

```
=--MID(B2:B22,SEARCH(",?????,",B2:B22)+1,5)
```

<s>Or even, since the starting position is *always* either the 13th or 14th character:</s>*

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(B2:B22,13,5),",")
```

<sub>* Won't work because of 'Sept'.</sub>